# Merging row data based in common Ids

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON data,

```
let data = [
 { "Id": 1, "Name": "Test", "Datacol1": "1", "Datacol2": 0,"Datacol3": 0 },
 { "Id": 2, "Name": "Test123", "Datacol1": "1", "Datacol2": 2, "Datacol3": 0 },
 { "Id": 1, "Name": "Test", "Datacol1": "0", "Datacol2": 1, "Datacol3": 0 },
 { "Id": 1, "Name": "Test", "Datacol1": "0", "Datacol2": 0, "Datacol3": 2 }
]
```

I want to merge the data and put it in single row data based on Id some thing like this Output =

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Test","Datacol1":"1","Datacol2":1,"Datacol3":2}, 
 {"Id":2,"Name":"Test123","Datacol1":"1","Datacol2":2,"Datacol3":0}]
```

can some one please help me in acheiving this.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array `reduce` & `findIndex`. Inside reduce back use the `findIndex` to check if the array contains an object where the `id` matches. If it matches then check if any other key value is 0. If it is zero then update with non zero value.

```js
let data = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Test",
    "Datacol1": "1",
    "Datacol2": 0,
    "Datacol3": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Test123",
    "Datacol1": "1",
    "Datacol2": 2,
    "Datacol3": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Test",
    "Datacol1": "0",
    "Datacol2": 1,
    "Datacol3": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Test",
    "Datacol1": "0",
    "Datacol2": 0,
    "Datacol3": 2
  }
]


let m = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findId = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.Id === curr.Id;
  });
  if (findId === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  } else {
    for (let keys in acc[findId]) {
      if (acc[findId][keys] === 0) {
        acc[findId][keys] = curr[keys]
      }
    }
  }
  return acc;

}, []);

console.log(m)
```